# Double-negation + logical and in Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I just ran across this code

```
var someBool = !!(o.a && o.a.t);
```

I was about to remove the double-negation, then realized it forces `someBool` to be a boolean value... Looking [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND), I find this example

```
a5 = "Cat" && "Dog"; // t && t returns "Dog"
```

This seems atypical based on my experience in other languages. I'd expect the logical and operation to *always* return a boolean value. Can anyone explain why this use case is supported in Javascript?

Also, is the code that sent me in this direction the best way to force a bool around logical and? I'm aware of `new Boolean`, but that doesn't return a primitive type like the double-negation, so perhaps that's the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators have an effect similar to boolean AND and OR, but they don't affect the expression value. The expressions are evaluated and the values tested with the JavaScript "truthiness" rules, but the overall expression value is that of the actual operand expressions (well, one of them).

Yes, that's different from C and Java and etc. JavaScript is a different language with its own rules.

The `Boolean` constructor can be called without `new` to perform a "truthiness" test and return a boolean primitive. Using `!!` is fairly idiomatic however.